# How to change rsyslog client name to export to server?

Tags: rsyslog

I have a remote rsyslog server up and running, and 10 servers are sending it's logs there as clients.

By default, they save it's logs in a directory with the same name as it's hostname. Let's say one of those servers has  hostname `client1`, then in the main server a directory is created called `/client1/` and it will be filled with the according log information for that client.

My boss wants that directory name to be `hostname-IP`. So if client1 has  IP 192.192.192.192, then it should create a `/client1-191.192.192.192/` directory on the main server with it's logs.

How/where I configure that?

Huge thanks in advance.

Warm regards.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file is on the server, /etc/rsyslog.conf or a file in /etc/rsyslog.d/ (or whatever other directory is included in /etc/rsyslog.conf). You'll need to restart rsyslogd for changes to take effect.

However, I don't think rsyslog makes the IP address available. You can take a look at [this list of variables](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v7-stable/configuration/properties.html) supported by rsyslog. If your clients are all on the same network and directly talking to the server, you might be able to use `fromhost-ip` but I've never tried that, myself.

Don't forget to back up your config files before making any changes ;) I've found rsyslog configuration to be a little finicky at times.